# profiling gcloud spark-submit with stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to check whether if it is possible to profile my spark-scala application, using google stackdriver profiler, when using gcloud spark-submit.

I have gone through the user guide/manual available on the google cloud docs but it is not clear. As per their documentation I can profile a JAVA application but there is no mention of how to setup this profiler for spark-scala applications on gcloud.

Would you happen to know anything about this? - your comments and suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the profiling of application written in scala is not supported the languages supported at the time of writting are Java, Python, Go, Node.js. You can also profile applications running outside of GCP, as per the official [Profiling Apllications](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/concepts-profiling#what_is_profiling).

I think a better solution is to review the possibilities as discussed in this StackOverflow thread[Profiling a Scala Spark application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900104/profiling-a-scala-spark-application)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did notice that there is no mention of "scala" in the list of profiling applications but still I was looking for an official "Nay" somewhere, which I haven't found yet. So just wanted to check.

Comment: I am selecting your answer as of now as it holds true i.e. at this time there is no way to profile spark applications on gcloud. But that will change within a month as I spoke to our company's google contact and the feature will be rolled out to public in like a month or so. I have seen the documents (on his laptop as they are under review currently).